# React: access data-attribute in <option> tag

Tags: reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I have this `select` JSX:

```
    <select className="form-control" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.props.value}>
      {options}
    </select>
```

with options being:

```
var options = this.props.options.map((option) => {
  return (<option key={option.slug} value={option.slug} data-country={option.country} data-continent={option.continent}>{option.value}</option>);
});
```

But I can't access the selected `data-country` of the option selected, since the value is accessed by `e.target.value`, and `e.target.dataset` is the dataset of the `select` tag and not the option selected tag:

```
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.name, e.target.value, e.target.dataset.continent, e.target.dataset.country);
  },
```

Is there a fix on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would pass around just the slug:

```
var options = this.props.options.map(option => {
    return (
        <option key={option.slug} value={option.slug}>
          {option.value}
        </option>
    );
});
```

... and then retrieve the data using the slug:

```
onChange: function(event, index, value) {
  var option = this.props.options.find(option => option.slug === value);
  this.props.onChange(this.props.name, value, option.continent, option.country);
}
```

(You'd replace the `.find` with a `forEach` or whatever JS you use if not ES6 capable.)

Answer (score 22):

I find @bjfletcher even more elegant than mine, but I'll report for the records:

I access the `<option>` DOM element through `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex]` in the `onChange` method:

```
  onChange: function(e) {
    var dataset = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].dataset;
    this.props.onChange(this.props.name, e.target.value, dataset.continent, dataset.country);
  },
```

Not sure of the compatibility though.

Comment: This is really terrific, always loved straight JS access to options. Someone can say that this line is longer `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex]`, but trust me guys this approach works everywhere in any browser - native support.

Comment: Working in React 17 too.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to use `refs`.

```
var options = this.props.options.map((option) => {
  return (<option ref={'option_ref_' + option.slug} ...></option>);
});
```

---

```
onChange: function(e) {
    var selectedOption = this.refs['option_ref_' + e.target.value];
    selectedOption['data-country']; //should work
    ...
},
```